# Does an app need admin perms to write to the user's home?

Tags: node.js, permissions

Good evening, and merry holidays

I was wondering, would an app (a packaged node.js app, to be precise) require administrator priviledges to write data to the users home (%USERPROFILE%) that executed it?

Comment: No. Try it and see.

Comment: ~~Sorry @JonathonReinhart, but it doesn't seem as if it does~~ Nope, nevermind, it does. Can you post this as an answer so that I can give you the reputation?